# IMFTransform::ProcessOutput Efficiency

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, ms-media-foundation

I've noticed that as apparently documented IMFTransform::ProcessOutput() for a resampler can only output one sample per call!  I guess its more orientated at large frame size video coding.  Given all the code I have been looking at as reference for related audio playback allocates one IMFMediaBuffer per call of ProcessOutput, this seems a little insane and terrible architecture - unless I am missing something?

It is especially bad from the point of view of media buffer usage.  For example a SourceReader decoding my test MP3 gives me chunks of about 64KB in one sample with one buffer.  Which is sensible.  But GetOutputStreamInfo() is requesting a media buffer of just 24 bytes per call for ProcessOutput().

64KB chunks => chopped into many 24B chunks => to further processing, seems very daft overhead (the resampler would be doing a lot of overhead per every 24 bytes, and enforcing that overhead later down the pipeline if its not consolidated).

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mftransform/nf-mftransform-imftransform-processoutput

Its says:

1. The MFT cannot return more than one sample per stream in a single call to ProcessOutput
2. The MFT writes the output data to the start of the buffer, overwriting any data that already exists in the buffer

So it's not even the case it can append to the end of partially full buffer attached to the sample.

I could create my own pooling object that supports the media buffers interface but pointer bumps into a vanilla locked media buffer I guess.  The only other option seemingly being to lock/copy those 24 bytes to another larger buffer for processing.  But this all seems excessive, and at the wrong granularity.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Here is a simplified sketch of my test so far:

```
...

status = transform->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
sample->Release();

while(1)
{
MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO outDetails{};
    MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outData{};
    IMFMediaBuffer* outBuffer;
    IMFSample* outSample;
    DWORD outStatus;

    
    
    status = transform->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &outDetails);
    
    status = MFCreateAlignedMemoryBuffer(outDetails.cbSize, outDetails.cbAlignment, &outBuffer);
    status = MFCreateSample(&outSample);
    status = outSample->AddBuffer(outBuffer);
    outBuffer->Release();
    
    outData.pSample = outSample;
    
    status = transform->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outData, &outStatus);
    if (status == MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT)
        break;
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Audio resampler is apparently capable of processing larger blocks at once

Comment: That would make sense but how to correctly discover that, or cause that to happen?

Comment: From the docs it appears that none of the parameters to ProcessOutput() will do what I want - as it can only return multiple samples in the case of multiple streams.  Capped at one sample per stream output per call?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can feed a larger buffer and have it back resampled. I am sure I did it multiple times in past, with MFT behavior behaving itself along the natural API lines. You should probably add some code to put this into more practical discussion (if by the time you have the code snippet things still can't get away from 24 byte blocks).

Comment: I added some example code.  All I can think you mean is to simply provide it with a larger buffer that is a multiple of 24 bytes?  But this seems undocumented behaviour?

Comment: I've noticed that MFCreateAlignedMemoryBuffer for 24 bytes actually gives me a sensible 64KB buffer.  But GetCurrentLength is always the same as GetMaxLength before before and after the call to ProcessOutput.  So I still can't see where it could be determined/encouraged to process more than 24 bytes at once despite the size of the buffer?

Comment: Exactly - just feed in larger input. It's normal documented behavior. There is no [`MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_SINGLE_SAMPLE_PER_BUFFER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mftransform/ne-mftransform-_mft_output_stream_info_flags) indication, so you can process multiple at once.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would set that - the only likely place seems ProcessOutput cOutputBufferCount parameter but then I would need a MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER struct per sample!  Also it seems my loop now doesn't seem to exit from MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT check.  (Every status is being checked and not fired by asserts btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code for you to prove that audio resamper is capable to process large audio blocks at once. It is good, efficient processing style:

```
winrt::com_ptr<IMFTransform> Transform;
winrt::check_hresult(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CResamplerMediaObject, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(Transform.put())));

WAVEFORMATEX InputWaveFormatEx { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 44100, 44100 * 2, 2, 16 };
WAVEFORMATEX OutputWaveFormatEx { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 48000, 48000 * 2, 2, 16 };

winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaType> InputMediaType;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMediaType(InputMediaType.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(MFInitMediaTypeFromWaveFormatEx(InputMediaType.get(), &InputWaveFormatEx, sizeof InputWaveFormatEx));
winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaType> OutputMediaType;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMediaType(OutputMediaType.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(MFInitMediaTypeFromWaveFormatEx(OutputMediaType.get(), &OutputWaveFormatEx, sizeof OutputWaveFormatEx));

winrt::check_hresult(Transform->SetInputType(0, InputMediaType.get(), 0));
winrt::check_hresult(Transform->SetOutputType(0, OutputMediaType.get(), 0));

MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO OutputStreamInfo { };
winrt::check_hresult(Transform->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &OutputStreamInfo));
_A(!(OutputStreamInfo.dwFlags & MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_SINGLE_SAMPLE_PER_BUFFER));

DWORD const InputMediaBufferSize = InputWaveFormatEx.nAvgBytesPerSec;
winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaBuffer> InputMediaBuffer;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(InputMediaBufferSize, InputMediaBuffer.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(InputMediaBuffer->SetCurrentLength(InputMediaBufferSize));
winrt::com_ptr<IMFSample> InputSample;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateSample(InputSample.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(InputSample->AddBuffer(InputMediaBuffer.get()));
winrt::check_hresult(Transform->ProcessInput(0, InputSample.get(), 0));

DWORD const OutputMediaBufferCapacity = OutputWaveFormatEx.nAvgBytesPerSec;
winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaBuffer> OutputMediaBuffer;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(OutputMediaBufferCapacity, OutputMediaBuffer.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(OutputMediaBuffer->SetCurrentLength(0));
winrt::com_ptr<IMFSample> OutputSample;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateSample(OutputSample.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(OutputSample->AddBuffer(OutputMediaBuffer.get()));
MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER OutputDataBuffer { 0, OutputSample.get() };
DWORD Status;
winrt::check_hresult(Transform->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &OutputDataBuffer, &Status));

DWORD OutputMediaBufferSize = 0;
winrt::check_hresult(OutputMediaBuffer->GetCurrentLength(&OutputMediaBufferSize));
```

You can see that after feeding one second of input, the output holds [almost] one second of data as expected.

[image]

Comment: Oh am I missing setting the output buffers content length to zero before calling ProcessOutput?  As by default then it seems creating buffers start with their contents being full.  Which would then make sense why my loop can't terminate as there is no apparent space in the output buffer...

Comment: I set length to zero to explicitly indicate that the length is updated by the MFT

Comment: Actually if I check the length after I explicitly set it to zero, its still not zero for some reason!  I will check your code more...

Comment: You are correct, setting the buffer size to a larger multiple of the size returned by GetOutputStreamInfo works fine.  I had a bug mixing up in/out samples in logging (hence my confusion over the buffer length being set), and it seems some of my excessive logging per sample for debugging was clogging things up somewhat!